# How to find if given python import statement is internal or external?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an excel sheet having thousands of import statements.
eg.,

```
from XYZ.loghelper import LogHelper,
import os,
from models import CustomUser, VerticalApp,
from django.http import HttpResponse,
```

Some of them are built-in and some are user defined.
Now I have to find whether they are user defined or built-in.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by builtin you mean "part of Python's stdlib" (python's "builtin" features, being "builtin", don't need to be imported at all). The definition of "user defined" is much more vague - is a 3rd part package like Django "builtin" or "user-defined" ?

But anyway: the short answer is that technically you CAN NOT tell just from the import statement. Modules are looked up in `sys.path` and the first matching module will be selected, so if you have a module named "os.py" in a local directory that comes before your Python installation's stdlib directory in `sys.path` then "import os" will indeed import your own "os.py" module instead of the stdlib's one. IOW, you need to use the exact same environment, import the module, and check the module's `__file__` attribute to find out where it's been imported from.

Now most python devs try to avoid shadowing stdlib's module names (for obvious reasons) so you can also just build a list (technically you want a `set` for better perfs but anyway) of Python's stdlibs modules names, parse your imports statements, and check if the name of the module to be imported belongs to the set of stdlib's names. This should yield correct results in most cases, but it's not garanteed to be 100% accurate.